# Bean class cannot be loaded due to a missing dependency: LazyDataModel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss

I'm using the primefaces framework to realise a lazy data table.
I imported the package:

```
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
```

in my EventViewer ManagedBean class.
I put the primefaces-6.1.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

After deploying the project on JBoss AS, when loading the page I get the following exception:

```
        2017-07-25 18:12:13,817 ERROR [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.managedbean] JSF will be unable to create managed bean eventViewer when it is requested.  The following problems where found:
         - Bean or property class com.imnet.oam.fe.event.EventViewer for managed bean eventViewer cannot be loaded due to a missing dependency: org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.
    2017-07-25 18:12:13,817 ERROR [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] Error Rendering View[/event.xhtml]
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to create managed bean eventViewer.  The following problems were found:
         - Bean or property class com.imnet.oam.fe.event.EventViewer for managed bean eventViewer cannot be loaded due to a missing dependency: org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:265)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at org.jboss.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:44)
        at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:63)
        at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:764)
        at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:1097) 
        [...]
```

This is the main error:

```
 - Bean or property class com.imnet.oam.fe.event.EventViewer for managed bean eventViewer cannot be loaded due to a missing dependency: org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Check if jar was deployed on application server. Probably not. If jar was not deployed, then you added it in build path, but not in deployment.

Comment: Jboss 4.2? Seriously?

Comment: @VasilLukach The jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder are meant to be used at runtime, and the primefaces tags are working in other pages. How should I add the jar in deployment in Eclipse?

Comment: @Kukeltje it does not depend on me :-)